# MVC Yii2 работа с логикой приложения

Tags: php, yii2, mvc

Начинаю изучать Yii2, и, как следствие - MVC.

Возникли вопросы:

- Если контроллеры, согласно лучшим практикам MVC, должны быть максимально "худыми", то можно ли в них делать простые обработки, вроде проверки на наличие слов из черного списка:

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Post; 

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

            // Псевдокод
            // Проверка на наличие слов из черного списка
            if(str_contains($model->text, 'some badword')){
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "Badword was found!");
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }

            if ($model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

- Как создавать большое количество логики? Для этого необходимо создавать отдельную функцию в модели? Или же есть какие-то ещё способы?

```
    public function validatePost($attribute, $params)
    {
        if(str_contains($this->text, 'some badword')){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

- Как правильно реализовать валидацию в зависимости от роли пользователя? Проверка роли должна быть в функции модели, или же в самом контроллере?

```
// В модели?
public function validatePost()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($user_id) == 'admin') {
            if( 123 == 123 ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if( 444 == 444 ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

или

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($user_id) == 'admin') {
            validateForAdmin();
        }else{
            validateForOthers();
        }
    }
```

- Можно ли хранить простую логику в представлениях? Если нет, то где её хранить?

```
// Псевдокод
if($user == 'admin'){
// Показывать этот инпут только для админа
 echo $form->field($model, 'author')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]); ?>
}

<?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'text') ?>
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

> Если контроллеры, согласно лучшим практикам MVC, должны быть максимально "худыми", то можно ли в них делать простые обработки, вроде проверки на наличие слов из черного списка:

А что такое `if(str_contains($model->text, 'some badword')){` ?  Это бизнес логика? Или валидация? Реакция на что? Если валидация - то валидация может происходить вся в модели. Если бизнес логика - то, убрать в сервис. Наверняка же будет проверка не на одно конкретное слово, а на проверку в списке, возможно там будет не просто `in_array` но и ещё какая-то логика. В итоге будет отдельный слой, в котором будет происходить проверка и возвращаться `bool`, так, что по-сути в контроллере будет происходить оперирование методом из этого слоя/сервиса и пр. который является участником бизнеса. Контроллер должен просто запросить инфу и ничего не знать про внутренние механизмы этого процесса (процесса определения является ли слово плохим или нет).

> Как создавать большое количество логики? Для этого необходимо создавать отдельную функцию в модели? Или же есть какие-то ещё способы?

Вы сейчас приводите только примеры с валидацией. На счёт неё ответ **почти** простой: для новичков и простых сайтов - валидацию стоит делать в модели. Если вы придерживаетесь принципа *DDD*, то всё гораздо сложнее. У Дмитрия Елисеева есть **[курс статей на эту тему](https://elisdn.ru/blog/104/domain-entities-modelling)** (как работать по DDD во фреймворке). Можете почитать, но, думаю, вам в это рано ещё уходить.

Если брать не валидацию, а именно бизнес-логику, то стОит выделить отдельный слой, где будет происходить именно реализация оной. А в контроллере просто запрашивать информацию у неё. Как я писал выше, контроллер ничего не должен знать о внутренних механизмах бизнеса, поэтому он просто запрашивает инфу или раскидывает данные между связанными сервисами и отдаёт данные пользователю. О внутренних взаимодействиях сущностей между собой лучше ему не знать. И уж тем более не писать логику `if (userRole === 'admin')`

---

По поводу проверки

```
if (userRole == 'admin') {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

то этого спокойно можно избежать сделав для админки и пользователя разные бэкенды (в *Yii2* например есть `advanced` версия, где специально разделено  `fronted` папка для клиента и `backend` папка для админки). В клиенткой части настроить правила так: **всё запрещено** по-умолчанию, а  разрешено только M, N, X.

> Можно ли хранить простую логику в представлениях? Если нет, то где её хранить?

`if($user == 'admin'){`

по поводу этого уже написал выше (разделить клиента и бэк изначально). Но всё же, для вёрстки применять некоторые правила нормально. Например если надо в `description` выводить максимально 50 символов, а если он больше, то выводить обрезанный текст + многоточие. Но большинство вещей, **по-моему личному мнению**, лучше убирать в бэк и в представлении, по-возможности, оперировать только заранее подготовленными данными. Тот же `$user == 'admin'` можно передать в шаблон как

```
return $this->render('create', [
    'model' => $model,
    'userIdAdmin' => $user->role == USER_ROLE_ADMIN
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Если контроллеры, согласно лучшим практикам MVC, должны быть максимально "худыми", то можно ли в них делать простые обработки, вроде проверки на наличие слов из черного списка

Решать Вам. Если есть время - лучше конечно вынести все в отдельную модель. Нет времени (например нужно скорее сдать заказчику) - пишите прямо в контроллере - потом, когда появится время - улучшите.

```php
public function actionCreate()
{
        $model = new Post; 
        if (\Yii::$app->request->isPost && count( \Yii::$app->request->post() ) > 0 && $model->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) ) {


            $view = 'create';
            $params = [ 'model' => $model ];
            // Псевдокод
            // Проверка на наличие слов из черного списка
            $result=str_contains($model->text, 'some badword');
            if ( !$result ) {
                if ( $model->save() ) {
                    $view = 'view';
                    $params = [ 'id' => $model->id ];
                }
            } else { \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "Badword was found!"); }

             return $this->render( $view, $params);
        }
        //А если load() вернет false ?
}
```

> Как создавать большое количество логики? Для этого необходимо создавать отдельную функцию в модели? Или же есть какие-то ещё способы?

Опять же - как Вам на данный момент удобно. Конечно, если у Вас это будет использовано не в одном месте и у Вас есть время все это "причесать" - выносите в модели, хелперы и тп - но решаете Вы.

```php
public function validatePost($attribute, $params)
    {
        $result = str_contains($this->text, 'some badword') );
        return $result;
    }
```

> Как правильно реализовать валидацию в зависимости от роли пользователя? Проверка роли должна быть в функции модели, или же в самом контроллере?

Зависит от того, что Вы проверяете - если доступ к определенным `actions` контроллера - то логично это сделать в контроллере, если же нужно просто сделать какие-то проверки или вычисления в зависимости от роли пользователя то в модели. Опять же немного "улучшу" Ваш код - никогда не используйте внутри кода прямое сравнение с текстом или каким-то ИД - выносите это в константы, чтобы потом не пришлось искать все сравнения по всему проекту - достаточно будет поменять в одном месте. Для проверки прав у `authManager` есть встроенный метод `can` которым Вы можете пользоваться.

```php
public function validatePost()
    {
        if (\Yii::$app->user->can(RoleAliases::ROLE_ADMIN) ) {
            //какие-то действия для пользователя-админа
        } else {
           //для всех остальных
        }

        return false;
    }
```

> Можно ли хранить простую логику в представлениях? Если нет, то где её хранить?

Можно. Особенно если Вы по каким-то причинам не разнесли `админку` и пользовательскую часть (бывают проекты где пользователь-админ логинится в общую часть сайта и пользуясь своими правами правит посты и тп сразу видя как они отображаются после этого у пользователей). Но, исходя из моей практики - потом в админскую часть захочется добавить что-то еще и еще, и еще... и у Вас будет просто мешанина из пользовательской части и админской - либо разбейте сайт на `админку` и пользовательскую часть, либо хотя бы разнесите в разные `view` (даже если будет много повторяющегося кода).